# Laravel Nova - Hide update icon (edit attached) on related resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-5.8

Does anyone know how I get rid of the update icon on a related resource's details page?

I'm talking about the icons on the right here;

[image: Nova Backend]

Events and  Time Slots have a many to many relationship.

They are related like so;

App/TimeSlot.php

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
}
```

App/Event.php

```
public function timeSlots()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\TimeSlot');
}
```

I have Nova resources and policies for each of those models too.

In my Time Slot policy, update is set to return false.

App/Nova/Policies/TimeSlotPolicy.php

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can update the time slot.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\TimeSlot  $timeSlot
 * @return mixed
 */
public function update(User $user, TimeSlot $timeSlot)
{
    return false;
}
```

and in my Event policy attachAnyTimeSlot and detachTimeSlot are both set to return false;

App/Nova/Policies/EventPolicy.php

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can attach a time slot to an event.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Event $event
 * @return mixed
 */
public function attachAnyTimeSlot(User $user, Event $event)
{
   return false;
}

/**
 * Determine whether the user can detach a time slot from an event.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Event $event
 * @param  \App\TimeSlot $timeSlot
 * @return mixed
*/
public function detachTimeSlot(User $user, Event $event, TimeSlot $timeSlot)
{
    return false;
}
```

The latter gets rid of the trash can icon that detaches the associated resource.

Nothing seems to get rid of the edit icon.

When I click it I can't do anything.

[image: Nova Backend 2]

For obvious reasons, I don't want it to appear at all.

Does anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: Maybe create a policy to restrict the creation?

Comment: I've already got a TimeSlot policy with `public function create` returning `false`. It's not affecting it.

Answer (score 5):

In your EventPolicy define

```
public function attachTimeSlot(User $user, Event $event, TimeSlot $timeSlot)
{
   return ! $event->timeslots->contains($timeslot);
}
```

Taken from this [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1003#issuecomment-497008278), take a look for more detail